# Changing multiple divs based on arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created an input section for users to write their own work. I have multiple divs to the side of this and I'd like to change the divs from a left and right arrow that can be clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menubody:nth-child(1)').show('slow');
  $('.menubody:nth-child(1)').hide('slow');
  $('.fa-caret-right').on({
    click: function() {
      var i = $('.menubody:visible').index();
      var len = $('.menubody').length;
      var next;
      if (i >= 0) {
        if (i == len - 1) {
          next = $('.menubody:eq(0)');
        } else {
          next = $('.menubody:eq(' + (i + 1) + ')');
        }
        $('.menubody:visible').hide();
        $(next).show();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

EDIT:

I have a working example (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3mw92yy/13/)) that changes and changes the content when 'right' is pressed.

How do I make it so the 'left' div moves the content to previous? And add more than one content area to change?

For an example layout of the usage (not jQuery working), please [see here](https://universitycompare.com/personal-statement-editor-2/).

Comment: I am not quite sure i get what you are after. Could you please elaborate it a bit? What does the "press 3 'rights arrows' to be pressed" means? What is the content that goes "1,2,3,4" ? Could you provide a scenario?

Comment: @Strahdvonzar, I have reworded the above question, "press the same div multiple times displaying content 1, then pressed again, displays content 2, and so on"

Comment: @Strahdvonzar I have updated my answer with a more thorough JS Fiddle to work from of my plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.prev()` and `.next()`. If they return a collection of zero length, use `.last()` and `.first()` instead to cycle through your content (not sure that you needed this).

```js
$(function() {
  $('.tabs-container div').not(':first-child').hide();

  $('#tabs li a').click(function() {
    var $clickedLink = $(this),
        $visible = $('.tabs-container div:visible');

    $visible.each(function(){
      var $this = $(this),
          $parentContainer = $this.parents('.tabs-container').eq(0),
          $toShow;
      
      if( $clickedLink.is('.prev') ){
         $toShow = $this.prev('div').length ? $this.prev('div') : $('div', $parentContainer).last();
      } else {
         $toShow = $this.next('div').length ? $this.next('div') : $('div', $parentContainer).first();
      }
                        
      $this.hide();
      $toShow.show();
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tabs">
  <li><a href="#" class="prev">Left Arrrow</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="next">Right Arrow</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs-container">
  <div id="content1">Content for link 1. Should display only when Link 1 is clicked.</div>
  <div id="content2">Content for link 2. Should display only when Link 2 is clicked.</div>
  <div id="content3">Content for link 3. Should display only when Link 3 is clicked.</div>
  <div id="content4">Content for link 4. Should display only when Link 4 is clicked.</div>
</div>

<p>Unrelated text is here. Text in this area is static and should display at all times.</p>

<div class="tabs-container">
  <div id="content1-2">Additional content for link 1. Should display only when Link 1 is clicked.</div>
  <div id="content2-2">Additional content for link 2. Should display only when Link 2 is clicked.</div>
</div>

<p>More unrelated text</p>

<div class="tabs-container">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What I am looking for, appreciate the easy to use content and references.

Comment: Hi Matvey, How would i add a third level of content that changes?

Comment: Edited the answer so that now it doesn't care how many .tabs-containers you have — two, three or several. See .each() in jQuery docs.

Comment: Hi Matvey, this didn't allow the divs to cycle through, I did change it, console also didn't spit out any errors? :/

Comment: Hm. Works fine for me in its current form. Tested in Firefox, Chrome, IE 11 on Windows.

Comment: Tested also on Mac (Safari, Chrome). It works. Please show what you've changed, if any :)

Comment: It did work and you are correct, I followed through a few errors with my own code, but fantastic and appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the nth-child() jQuery selector here. Simply increment the value of n every time the button right is clicked and decrease the value of n every time the left arrow is clicked.

```
$('#left-arrow').on('click', function(){
  var i++; 
  $('main-div:nth-child(i-1)').hide();
  $('main-div:nth-child(i)').show();
})
```

Here's a link to read more : [W3 Schools :nth-child() selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_nthchild.asp)

Comment: I have edited my original question along with a JS Fiddle, that is a reasonably close to what I 'd like to achieve.

Comment: Yup, seems to be working nicely. Hope I was of some help.